# How to use my api key with a loader?

Tags: android, curl, loader

I already have an app that uses loaders for an api but I want to adapt it for a new api. The problem is that the new api was given to me in this format:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Token <myToken>" "https://localelections.usvotefoundation.org/api/v1/states"
```

which I can use just fine in the terminal but I don't know how to use it in Android Studio. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Some code from my Utils file:

```
// Returns new URL object from the given string URL.
private static URL createUrl(String stringUrl) {
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(stringUrl);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem building the URL ", e);
    }
    return url;
}

//Make an HTTP request to the given URL and return a String as the response.
private static String makeHttpRequest(URL url) throws IOException {
    String jsonResponse = "";

    // If the URL is null, then return early.
    if (url == null) {
        return jsonResponse;
    }

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect();

        // If the request was successful (response code 200),
        // then read the input stream and parse the response.
        if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            jsonResponse = readFromStream(inputStream);
        } else {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error response code: " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem retrieving the JSON results.", e);
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        if (inputStream != null) {
            // Closing the input stream could throw an IOException, which is why
            // the makeHttpRequest(URL url) method signature specifies than an IOException
            // could be thrown.
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }
    return jsonResponse;
}
```

Comment: You can request it by using 'GET' with header which included Authorization key and tokean.

Comment: @kimkevin Hey. Thanks for your response. I added some code from Utils file above. I should be able to use makeHttpRequest for that, right?

Comment: I will make a answer and help you to figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `Authorization` to header by using `HttpURLConnection` like this.

```
urlConnection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", yourTokenHere);
```

Comment: Much appreciated.